# Windows 10 Kiosk mode issue

Tags: kiosk, iot

We have got small IoT device with Win10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 (Version 1809 OS Build 17763.1697). We want use it for Kiosk but there is no options to activate it. In **Settings -> Accounts** we don't have any options:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjfO2.png)

When I type kiosk in search bar it's showing but nothing is happens when I click on it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58KOQ.png)

Commands **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth** and **sfc /scannow** didn't help.
New admin account also.

Comment: You are not finding the option since you are using a LTSC version of Windows.  By default LTSC doesn't have default UWP applications.  It's also possible the device is being managed by a active directory domain, there is a group policy, that hides any option within Settings the Administrator wants.  Is your device managed by a Active Directory domain?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your reply. Device isn't managed by AD. It's possible to add Kiosk feature to LTSC version?

Comment: I don’t believe it is